# No me genera enlace para recuperar contraseña en spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

En este caso estoy intentado recuperar la contraseña, estoy haciendo un proyecto y estoy a nivel local al momento de enviar el correo para recuperar la contraseña y al abrirlo me genera un error ya que a probarlo en el Spring no me genera el localhost, si no directamente me genera es a partir del /, el ejemplo sería que debería generarme el localhost:8080/reset_password?tokenpnoBiXIm0yxB19Z6cSQLjpmvyCUdovbe7MQzUp4rscaM8 pero me genera es solo /reset_password?tokenpnoBiXIm0yxB19Z6cSQLjpmvyCUdovbe7MQzUp4rscaM8 y creo que eso es lo que me genera el conflicto y la verdad no veo error de código ni nada, si alguien me puede ayudar le agradezco mucho, gracias.

```
    @PostMapping("/recuperar")
    public String Contraseña(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String token = RandomString.make(45);
        
        //System.out.println("Email: " + email);
        //System.out.println("Token: " + token);
        
        try {
            usuarioImp.updateResetPassword(token, email);
            String resetPasswordLink = Utility.getSiteURL(request) + "/reset_password?token" + token;
            System.out.println(resetPasswordLink);
        } catch (CustomerNotFoundException ex) {
            model.addAttribute("error", ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return "recuperarcontraseña";
    }

public class Utility { 
    public static String getSiteURL(HttpServletRequest request) { 
        String siteURL = request.getRequestURI().toString();
        return siteURL.replace(request.getServletPath(), "");
    }
}
```

Comment: No ves error porque seguramente el error no esté en **este** código. La llamada a `Utility.getSiteURL(request)` te está devolviendo un String vacío

Comment: @PabloLozano Mira esto es lo que tengo en Utility,                                            public class Utility {
 public static String getSiteURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String siteURL = request.getRequestURI().toString();
  return siteURL.replace(request.getServletPath(), "");
 }
}

Comment: Mira  esto es lo que tengo en Utility, entonces no se si eso me este afectando        ```                                                                                                                          public class Utility {
 public static String getSiteURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String siteURL = request.getRequestURI().toString();
  return siteURL.replace(request.getServletPath(), "");
 }
}                                                                                                                                    ```

Comment: Creo que tesobre el replace dentro de ese método

Comment: Si era la parte del Utility, muchas gracias @PabloLozano